# Excel: Copy Row to New Tab if Cell Contains Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I'm a complete novice when it comes to Excel, I've Googled it and it's come up with some responses that I don't understand in the slightest.  Most of which are things I need to do in Visual Basic?

Essentially what I want is to set up several tabs for individual users, that generate from the main tab.  All of which are set up already.

So IF Row R on Main Sheet has NO (Persons Initials)
Copy this row to the Nick tab (There will be 20+ rows for each user, not sure if that changes anything)

Any help would be incredible and massively appreciated!

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Do you know how to write macros in Excel VBA?

Comment: Hi, I've never written a Macro in Excel before no.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably get a start by recording a macro. Here's a link on how to do that: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-macro-HP010342374.aspx#BMrecordmacro. After you click record, just start doing what you want done manually. That will show you some of the syntax. In this case, it will probably be easiest for you to format your summary data as a table, filter it by each person's initials and then copy the results to the individual tabs. Your recorded code is probably going to look something like this:

```
Sub CopyNO()
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "NO"
Range("Table1[#All]").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("NO").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

To clean up the code you record, you'll want to try to change anything that says ActiveSheet to something like Sheets("SheetName") and, ideally, get rid of any .Select commands by instead using whatever is actually done with the selection. Here you might end up with something like:

```
Sub CopyNO()
Sheets("Summary").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "NO"
Worksheets("Summary").Range("Table1").Copy _
   Destination:=Worksheets("NO").Range("A5")
End Sub
```